In tidyterra for R, could facet_grid be implemented?
In R, package tidyterra allows use of facet_wrap(~lyr) to plot multiple spatial raster layers in one figure.
library(terra)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyterra)
x <- rast(array(data = rnorm(120,0,1), dim=c(5,5,4)))
names(x) <- c("A_1", "B_1", "A_2", "B_2")
ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster(data = x) +
  facet_wrap(~lyr)

Is there any way of implementing facet_grid in tidyterra so that, in the case above for example, the rows would be labelled 1 and 2, and columns would be labelled A and B?
This would require a spatraster object to have more than one attribute (the name of the layer) associated with it, I guess.


Maybe this? fortify to a tibble with tidyterra method, and then pivot, split labels and plot as a regular data frame.
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.78
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyterra)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'tidyterra'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
x <- rast(array(data = rnorm(120, 0, 1), dim = c(5, 5, 4)))
names(x) <- c("A_1", "B_1", "A_2", "B_2")
ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster(data = x) +
  facet_wrap(~lyr, ncol = 2) +
  coord_sf(crs = pull_crs(x)) +
  labs(x = "", y = "")



# Fortify method converting to data.frame
x_frt <- fortify(x) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(x:y), names_to = "lyr", values_to = "value") %>%
  mutate(
    col_n = stringr::str_split_i(lyr, "_", 1),
    row_n = stringr::str_split_i(lyr, "_", 2)
  )



x_frt
#> # A tibble: 100 × 6
#>        x     y lyr    value col_n row_n
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#>  1   0.5   4.5 A_1   -0.318 A     1    
#>  2   0.5   4.5 B_1    1.02  B     1    
#>  3   0.5   4.5 A_2   -0.612 A     2    
#>  4   0.5   4.5 B_2    0.989 B     2    
#>  5   1.5   4.5 A_1   -2.68  A     1    
#>  6   1.5   4.5 B_1    1.83  B     1    
#>  7   1.5   4.5 A_2   -0.792 A     2    
#>  8   1.5   4.5 B_2    0.132 B     2    
#>  9   2.5   4.5 A_1    0.274 A     1    
#> 10   2.5   4.5 B_1    0.128 B     1    
#> # ℹ 90 more rows

ggplot(x_frt, aes(x, y, z = value, fill = value)) +
  geom_raster() +
  facet_grid(vars(row_n), vars(col_n)) +
  coord_sf(crs = pull_crs(x)) +
  labs(x = "", y = "")


Created on 2024-07-30 with reprex v2.1.1


Session info

sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14)
#>  os       Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu
#>  ui       X11
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  C.UTF-8
#>  ctype    C.UTF-8
#>  tz       UTC
#>  date     2024-07-30
#>  pandoc   3.1.1 @ /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/quarto/bin/tools/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version date (UTC) lib source
#>  class         7.3-22  2023-05-03 [2] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#>  classInt      0.4-10  2023-09-05 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  cli           3.6.3   2024-06-21 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  codetools     0.2-20  2024-03-31 [2] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#>  colorspace    2.1-1   2024-07-26 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  curl          5.2.1   2024-03-01 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  data.table    1.15.4  2024-03-30 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  DBI           1.2.3   2024-06-02 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  digest        0.6.36  2024-06-23 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  dplyr         1.1.4   2023-11-17 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  e1071         1.7-14  2023-12-06 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  evaluate      0.24.0  2024-06-10 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  fansi         1.0.6   2023-12-08 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  farver        2.1.2   2024-05-13 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  fastmap       1.2.0   2024-05-15 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  fs            1.6.4   2024-04-25 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  generics      0.1.3   2022-07-05 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  ggplot2     * 3.5.1   2024-04-23 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  glue          1.7.0   2024-01-09 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  gtable        0.3.5   2024-04-22 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  highr         0.11    2024-05-26 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  htmltools     0.5.8.1 2024-04-04 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  KernSmooth    2.23-24 2024-05-17 [2] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#>  knitr         1.48    2024-07-07 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  labeling      0.4.3   2023-08-29 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  lifecycle     1.0.4   2023-11-07 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  magrittr      2.0.3   2022-03-30 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  munsell       0.5.1   2024-04-01 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  pillar        1.9.0   2023-03-22 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  proxy         0.4-27  2022-06-09 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  purrr         1.0.2   2023-08-10 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  R6            2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  Rcpp          1.0.13  2024-07-17 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  reprex        2.1.1   2024-07-06 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  rlang         1.1.4   2024-06-04 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  rmarkdown     2.27    2024-05-17 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  rstudioapi    0.16.0  2024-03-24 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  scales        1.3.0   2023-11-28 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  sf            1.0-16  2024-03-24 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  stringi       1.8.4   2024-05-06 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  stringr       1.5.1   2023-11-14 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  terra       * 1.7-78  2024-05-22 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  tibble        3.2.1   2023-03-20 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  tidyr         1.3.1   2024-01-24 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  tidyselect    1.2.1   2024-03-11 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  tidyterra   * 0.6.1   2024-06-08 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  units         0.8-5   2023-11-28 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  utf8          1.2.4   2023-10-22 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  vctrs         0.6.5   2023-12-01 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  withr         3.0.0   2024-01-16 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  xfun          0.46    2024-07-18 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  xml2          1.3.6   2023-12-04 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  yaml          2.3.10  2024-07-26 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#> 
#>  [1] /cloud/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.4
#>  [2] /opt/R/4.4.1/lib/R/library
#> 
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────


Many thanks. I thought there might be a direct geom_spatraster solution but this geom_raster solution does the job exactly.
